# Populate list based on selected value in ag grid- Angular 2

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have a scenario whereby, I need to **Populate List B** (in the dropdown) based on selection of **List A** (in the dropdown) in the AG-GRID. These list are separately used in a **CellRenderer Framework**. I can load the entire List A and List B using **CellRenderer Framwork** but, its more challenging when I try to load the specific List when one dropdown value is selected.

Please let me know the solution if you guys have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following: Bing the value of your first select to a variable `firstSelectValue`. Then write a function like

```
selectValuesDependingOn(firstValue) {
    if (firstValue == ...) return [a,b,c];
    return [x,y,z];
}
```

And use it for the options in your second select like

```
<option *ngFor="let option of selectValuesDependingOn(firstSelectValue)">
```